# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, date

when iam trying to write this select in vb.net and sqlserver database:

```
da = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from UserComeView where ( ComeUserFullName=" & cmb_user.SelectedValue & " ) and ( ComeDate between '" & Date1.Value & "' and '" & Date2.Value & "')", sql.sqlcon)
```

comes this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Comment: You should be using parameters in your SQL queries - as written, you're currently vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Why do you need to convert from Date to String? Why can't you just pass the Date as a parameter?

Comment: Please consider the SQL Injection concerns, but in the meantime you may want to add 
   .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Comment: What is the datatype in the database of the ComeDate field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that `ComeDate` is some type of Date field. I altered your Select command to include parameters. Defining the datatype in the `.Add` method should clear up your conversion problem. I had to guess at the datatype. Check the datatype in your database. Then pass the command, which includes the connection, to the constructor of the `DataAdapter`.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From UserComeView Where ComeUserFullName = @FullName And ComeDate Between @Date1 And @Date2;", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FullName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = cmb_user.SelectedValue
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date1", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Date1.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date2", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Date2.Value
        Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```